# How does inRequestScope method works?

Tags: inversifyjs

```js
// GameFactory.ts
export default class GameFactory {
  public static create(): AbstractGame {
    DependencyRegistrar.registerDependencies();
    return container.get<AbstractGame>(TYPES.Game);
  }
}
```

```js
// AbstractGame.ts
export default abstract class AbstractGame {
   constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.Player)
    @named("localPlayer")
    protected localPlayer: AbstractPlayer,
    @inject(TYPES.Player)
    @named("opponent")
    protected opponent: AbstractPlayer,
  ) {}
}
```

```js
// AbstractPlayer.ts
export default abstract class AbstractPlayer {
@inject(TYPES.InputManager) inputManager!: InputManager;
@inject(TYPES.CharacterController) protected charCtrl!: CharacterController;

constructor() {}
...
}
```

```js
// CharacterController.ts
export default class CharacterController {
@inject(TYPES.InputManager) inputManager!: InputManager;

constructor() {}
...
}
```

```js
// DependencyRegistrar.ts
export default class DependencyRegistrar {
  public static registerDependencies(): void {
    container
      .bind<InputManager>(TYPES.InputManager)
      .to(InputManager)

    container
      .bind<CharacterController>(TYPES.CharacterController)
      .to(CharacterController);

    container
      .bind<AbstractGame>(TYPES.Game)
      .to(Game)
      .inSingletonScope()

    container
      .bind<AbstractPlayer>(TYPES.Player)
      .to(LocalPlayer)
      .inSingletonScope()
      .whenTargetNamed("localPlayer");

    container
      .bind<AbstractPlayer>(TYPES.Player)
      .to(Opponent)
      .inSingletonScope()
      .whenTargetNamed("opponent");
  }
}
```

Hi. These are a portion of my bindings. My `AbstractPlayer` injects the `InputManager` and the `CharacterController` classes. Also, the `CharacterController` class injects the `InputManager` class and I want to get the same instance of `InputManager` that the `AbstractPlayer` class injects.

I tried using the `inRequestScope` method on the `InputManager` binding but it didn't work as expected and I'm getting the same instance of the `InputManager` for both the local player and the opponent.